# Splitting a binary value in MIPS assembly for UTF-8 program (MARS)

Tags: assembly, utf-8, binary, mips, mars-simulator

In an MIPS assembly program I am working on, I am currently taking decimal integer values and outputting their binary and hexadecimal UTF-8 values. While maneuvering between decimal, hexadecimal, and binary is no issue, I was wondering how I might be able to split the binary form of a given input into segments of its bits. For example, suppose I had the decimal number 1898 (or 11101101010 in binary) and wanted to create variables to store the first five binary bits (11101) and the final six bits (101010) separately. While originally I wanted to create a subtraction case, making such a case universal did not seem possible.

EDIT 1:
So I have attempted to use andi and a sll case for my first else statement which is written

```
Else1:
bgt $s1, 0x7FF, Else2       # if j > 0x7FF branch to Else2
addi $t1, $zero, 49280      # n = 49280 or 110 00000 10 000000 in binary
andi $t2, $s1, 11111000000  # a = first five bits of j
andi $t3, $s1, 00000111111  # b = last six bits of j
sll $t2, $t2, 2         # a is shifted two bits to the left
add $s2, $t1, $t3       # n = n + b
add $s2, $s2, $t2       # n = n + a
j Print             # jump to print section
```

However, when tracking register values I have noticed that nothing is going into register $t3 at the second andi statement.

Comment: You're looking for shift and AND instructions to extract a range of bits to the bottom of a separate register.

Comment: I've started to implement some of these ideas and have encountered an issue with a second andi detailed above. If you think you can spot the issue, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I've corrected it

Comment: It's usually a lot easier to write constants in hex (`0xfc0`).  Some assemblers let you write `0b11111` or `1111b` or something for binary, though.